# Prevent showing “out of stock” products as “related products” in Shopify

Tags: shopify

Please can anybody help. I'm trying to prevent showing "out of stock"-products as "related product"
I don't want to completely hide the product from being visible.

Here is the code I currently have in the related.liquid file

```
{% comment %}ly_global_begin{% endcomment %}{% include 'ly-global' %}{% comment %}ly_global_end{% endcomment %}
{% assign found_a_collection = false %}
{% if collection == null or collection.handle == 'frontpage' or collection.handle == 'all' %}
    {% for c in product.collections %}
        {% if found_a_collection == false and c.handle != 'all-products' and c.handle != 'frontpage' and c.handle != 'all' %}
            {% assign found_a_collection = true %}
            {% assign coll = c %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
   {% assign found_a_collection = true %}
   {% assign coll = collection %}
{% endif %}


{% if found_a_collection and coll.products.size > 1 %}
   <div id="related" class="{% if settings.mobile_related_items %}hide-mobile{% endif %} clearfix">
      <h3>{% comment %}ly_i18n_replace_for_[ 'products.general.related_items' | t ]_begin{% endcomment %}{% capture ly_template %}{{ 'products.general.related_items' | t }}{% endcapture %}{% include 'ly-static-string' with '1413610' %}{% if ly_translation %}{% assign escape_content = true %}{% assign ly_template = ly_translation %}{% else %}{% assign escape_content = false %}{% endif %}{% if escape_content %}{{ ly_template | escape}}{% else %}{{ ly_template }}{% endif %}{% comment %}ly_i18n_replace_end{% endcomment %}</h3>
      {% assign max_items = '' %}
      <ul class="block-grid columns4 collection-th">
         {% for prd in coll.products %}
            {% if prd.handle != product.handle and max_items != '****' %}
               <li>
                  <a class="prod-th" title="{% comment %}ly_code_replace_for_[ prd.title | escape ]_begin{% endcomment %}{% include 'ly-title' with prd %}{% assign c7cdd42304af0cf1669bffa56a709695 = ly_translation %}{{ c7cdd42304af0cf1669bffa56a709695 | escape }}{% comment %}ly_code_replace_end{% endcomment %}" href="{{ prd.url }}">
                        <span class="thumbnail">
                           <img alt="{{ prd.images.first.alt | escape }}" src="{{ prd.images.first | product_img_url: 'medium' }}">
                        </span>
                          <span class="product-title">
                              <span class="title">
                                 {% comment %}ly_code_replace_for_[ prd.title | escape ]_begin{% endcomment %}{% include 'ly-title' with prd %}{% assign c7cdd42304af0cf1669bffa56a709695 = ly_translation %}{{ c7cdd42304af0cf1669bffa56a709695 | escape }}{% comment %}ly_code_replace_end{% endcomment %} 
                              </span>      
                              <span class="price{% unless prd.available %} sold-out{% endunless %}">
                                 {% if prd.available %}
                                    {% if prd.compare_at_price > prd.price %}
                                       <del>{% assign geolizr_price = prd.compare_at_price  %}{% include 'geolizr-currency' with geolizr_price %}{{prd.compare_at_price | money | prepend: geolizr_prepend_code | append: geolizr_append_code }}</del> {% assign geolizr_price = prd.price  %}{% include 'geolizr-currency' with geolizr_price %}{{prd.price | money | prepend: geolizr_prepend_code | append: geolizr_append_code }}
                                    {% else %}
                                       {% if prd.price_varies %}<small>{% comment %}ly_i18n_replace_for_[ 'products.general.from' | t ]_begin{% endcomment %}{% capture ly_template %}{{ 'products.general.from' | t }}{% endcapture %}{% include 'ly-static-string' with '1413611' %}{% if ly_translation %}{% assign escape_content = true %}{% assign ly_template = ly_translation %}{% else %}{% assign escape_content = false %}{% endif %}{% if escape_content %}{{ ly_template | escape}}{% else %}{{ ly_template }}{% endif %}{% comment %}ly_i18n_replace_end{% endcomment %}</small> {% endif%}{% assign geolizr_price = prd.price  %}{% include 'geolizr-currency' with geolizr_price %}{{prd.price | money | prepend: geolizr_prepend_code | append: geolizr_append_code }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                 {% else %}
                                    {% comment %}ly_i18n_replace_for_[ 'products.product.sold_out' | t ]_begin{% endcomment %}{% capture ly_template %}{{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}{% endcapture %}{% include 'ly-static-string' with '1413612' %}{% if ly_translation %}{% assign escape_content = true %}{% assign ly_template = ly_translation %}{% else %}{% assign escape_content = false %}{% endif %}{% if escape_content %}{{ ly_template | escape}}{% else %}{{ ly_template }}{% endif %}{% comment %}ly_i18n_replace_end{% endcomment %}
                                 {% endif %}
                              </span>         
                           </span>
                           {% if prd.compare_at_price > prd.price %}
                              {% if settings.show_sale_sticker %}
                                 <span class="sale round">{% comment %}ly_i18n_replace_for_[ 'products.general.sale' | t ]_begin{% endcomment %}{% capture ly_template %}{{ 'products.general.sale' | t }}{% endcapture %}{% include 'ly-static-string' with '1413613' %}{% if ly_translation %}{% assign escape_content = true %}{% assign ly_template = ly_translation %}{% else %}{% assign escape_content = false %}{% endif %}{% if escape_content %}{{ ly_template | escape}}{% else %}{{ ly_template }}{% endif %}{% comment %}ly_i18n_replace_end{% endcomment %}</span>
                              {% endif %}
                           {% endif %}
                  </a>
               </li>
               {% capture max_items %}{{max_items}}*{% endcapture %}
            {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
      </ul>     
   </div>   
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

`{% if prd.handle != product.handle and max_items != '****' %}`

to this

`{% if prd.handle != product.handle and max_items != '****' and product.available == true %}`

P.S. I'm not sure if `max_items` is properly being used.